# Launching OplRun has encountered a problem. A reference to undefined variable C is shown while trying to use oplrun. Why?

Tags: windows, error-handling, runtime-error, cplex, opl

[image]

I tried like this but it is not working. The picture is attached  below.

Answer (score 0):

You can run oplrun from command line:

[image]